# Is it possible to update view from function swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have such view:

```
struct PersonalPage: View {
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                VStack {
                    Text("88")
                    Text("88")
                    Text("88")
                    
                }
            }
            
        }.onAppear {
            self.getPersonalData()
        }
    }
    
    var mainSession = Session(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, interceptor: EnvInterceptor())
    
    
    func getPersonalData(){
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:Pathes.init().userInfo)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        mainSession.request(request).responseDecodable(of:PersonalInfo.self) { (response) in
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                guard let userData = response.value else { return }
                self.preferences.set(userData.applicant.email,forKey: "applicant_email")
                self.preferences.set(userData.applicant.id, forKey: "applicant_id")
                self.preferences.set(userData.applicant.delete, forKey: "applicant_can_delete")
                self.preferences.set(userData.applicant.caseManager, forKey: "casemanager_assigned")
                self.preferences.set(userData.applicant.photoChecksum, forKey: "photo_checksum")
                
                
                self.preferences.set(userData.consultant.firstname, forKey: "cons_firstname")
                self.preferences.set(userData.consultant.lastname, forKey: "cons_lastname")
                self.preferences.set(userData.consultant.id, forKey: "cons_id")
                
                self.preferences.synchronize()
                
                
                HomeScreen().self.addBadges()
                
            case .failure:
                print(response.response?.statusCode as Any)
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

and as you can see I have method for getting data from api. So, is it possible to update for example `Text` with some text from server response and if it possible how I can do it? As I understood I can't do smth like global view variable and have access to its elements from any place of struct?

Comment: Start from [Data Flow Through SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/)

Comment: @Asperi, I saw this video before published this question, but I can't understand how to reach my target :(

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a `@State` property for each of your desired Text views you can use them in the View body and update them from your function. Here is a brief example I hope helps;

```
struct PersonalPage: View {
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

    @State private var textOne = ""
    @State private var textTwo = ""
    @State private var textThree = ""


    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                VStack {
                    Text(textOne)
                    Text(textTwo)
                    Text(textThree)
                }
            }   
        }.onAppear {
            self.getPersonalData()
        }
    } 

    func getPersonalData() {
        textOne = "Hello World"
        textTwo = "Map"
    
         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
             textThree = "Delayed Text"
         }
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct PersonalPage: View {
@State var personalDataModel = PersonalDataModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment:.leading){
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
            VStack {
                Text(personalDataModel.cons_lastname)
                Text(personalDataModel.cons_firstname)
                Text(personalDataModel.photo_checksum)
            }
        }
    }.onAppear {
        self.getPersonalData()
    }
}

var mainSession = Session(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, interceptor: EnvInterceptor())

func getPersonalData(){
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:Pathes.init().userInfo)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    mainSession.request(request).responseDecodable(of:PersonalInfo.self) { (response) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            guard let userData = response.value else { return }
            let personalDataModel = PersonalDataModel()
            personalDataModel.applicant_email = userData.applicant.email
            personalDataModel.applicant_id = userData.applicant.id
            personalDataModel.cons_firstname = userData.consultant.firstname
            self.personalDataModel = personalDataModel
            
            HomeScreen().self.addBadges()
            
        case .failure:
            print(response.response?.statusCode as Any)
        }
        
    }
    
    
    }
}

struct PersonalDataModel : Codable {
public var applicant_email: String = ""
public var id: String = ""
public var applicant_can_delete: String = ""
public var applicant_id: String = ""
public var designation: String = ""
public var casemanager_assigned: String = ""
public var photo_checksum: String = ""
public var cons_firstname: String = ""
public var cons_lastname: String = ""
public var cons_id: String = ""
}
```